# c++: statically link against different versions of the same library?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, static-linking

I include a 3rd party library in my code. I maintain a static link to it and am unable to support dynamic links (which would be the easiest solution to the problem but is not possible in my case). Recently, the developer of that library posted an update which includes some breaking changes (function parameters changed within the API, features added/removed, etc).

I have users who rely on features of the old version of the library, and users who will want the new features as well. I would like to avoid having to compile multiple version of my code in order to support multiple versions of the library. Instead, I would like to include a switch in my UI that allows users to choose which version of the library they'd like to use.

When it comes to compiling my code, if I try a naive solution and simply include both old and new libraries, I get multiply-defined-symbols errors (because not all function signatures between the versions are different) and such....and many of the header filenames are identical so there's no straight-forward way differentiate between the two in many cases.

I was thinking of creating an intermediate wrapper library for both libraries...the wrappers would be compiled separately and their APIs couched in different namespaces, and then included in my code. I would then call a different wrapper depending on my needs, which would access the appropriate library internally....but is such a thing possible? I wanted to ask here before putting in all the legwork of setting up those wrappers, only to run into the same multiple-symbol-definition errors again....

Or is there another way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your described solution is pretty much *the* way to go about this. You won't run into multiple-definition errors so long as your intermediate wrappers only expose your custom interface and not the symbols from the 3rd party library.

Comment: There's various things the underlying library could do, though, that would break this scheme (if both are used at the same time). Relying on a named system resource for example. Binding a specific local TCP port. etc... 
But yeah, generally, it is the way to go.